# How to extend a type in Typescript Ad-hoc

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a class called `ClassA` which has 10 props. Now in my class I want to have an instance of `ClassA` and adding a prop called `isValid` but I don't want to create a new class and extend it

```
export class ClassA {
  constructor(
    public active: boolean,
    public createdBy: string,
    public createdTimestamp: Date,
    public entityState: string,
    public scopeType: string,
    public scopeValue: string,
    public tableDescription: string,
    public tableId: number,
    public tableName: string,
    public changeHistoryPreserveDays = 0,
    public createdString: string
  ) { }
}
```

in my component:

```
myInstance : any  = {
    isValid : true
 }

foo(classA: ClassA) {
   this.myInstance = {...myInstance, ...classA};
}
```

Then by using `any` I will loose the type checking.

My question is, is there any quick way of expanding a class ad-hoc, without defining a new class

Comment: Can you make your code a [mcve]? Without that it's hard to be sure the answer will be relevant.  I'd say don't use `any`; use the right type like `ClassA & {isValid: boolean}` or whatever you want.

Comment: @jcalz this is it, btw https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-extend-type-adhoc

Comment: I'd say `Partial<ClassA> & {isValid: boolean}` instead of `any`, since you initialize it to something with none of the properties of `ClassA`.  If you have a use case I can help more, otherwise that's my suggestion

Comment: @jcalz yes, I figured it out from your first comment, you can post the answer so that I can mark it as answer

Answer (score 1):

> Credits to @jcalz

I wrote the answer here in case some one else looking for same thing.

As @jcalz mentioned in comments the below code makes it typed

```
myInstance: Partial<ClassA> & {isValid: boolean} = { isValid : true }
```